# Google sheets API: Read cell formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using “Google_Service_Sheets” API to read values from google spreadsheets below is sample code.

```
$range = 'SHEET_NAME!A1:A5';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
if (empty($values)) {
  print 'No data found.\n';
} else {
  foreach ($values as $row) {
     for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($row); $i++) {
         echo $row[$i].'\n';
     }
  }
}
```

Values in the spreadsheet are stored with Round instead for Number format with decimal i.e. 42 instead of 41.5 (formula for this cell is: fx: 30+ 11.5)
The above code is giving me values from cell i.e. 42 but I want to fetch fx value which is 30 + 11.5 i.e. 41.5.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `valueRenderOption` with the parameter `FORMULA`, see [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption)

Subsequently, you can withdraw your original value from the formula and proceed as desired.

**Sample:**

```php
$range = 'SHEET_NAME!A1:A5';
$options = [
    'valueRenderOption' => 'FORMULA'
];
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range, $options);
$values = $response->getValues();
}
```