# Get the custom function called in a cell in Google Sheet (not the actual value of the cell)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I want to get in script the function called in a cell, but not the value returned from that function.

Is it possible in Apps Script ? I'm losing my mind trying to find how to do it since I got a LOT of cells in my sheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390049/google-sheets-api-read-cell-formula

Comment: getCurrentCell()

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your question is unclear because you are not showing any code nor your desired results. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Range.getFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula) to get the formula in a cell in Apps Script.

If the formula uses a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), and the function is in the script project as the code that inspects it, you can get the full source code of the custom function by using [`Function.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString).

There is no programmatic access to the source code of Google Apps Script's own classes and methods, nor to the source code of [named functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534) (currently in January 2023).

To get the formula using another formula, use [`formulatext()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365792).