# How to retrieve a cell's formula instead of its value in Google Sheets?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I have a C# program that I want to CRUD a Google sheet. In the following code snippet I am inside a for loop and there are two fields in the sheet, one with a direct value (displayed as a DateTime), the other is a TEXT() formula accessing the other cell.

```
DateTime dt_date_added = Convert.ToDateTime(row[9]);
string str_current_date_added_composite = 
  row[10].ToString().Trim();
```

dt_date_added is getting the correct values (10/1/2022 11:30:02 AM, 9/29/2022 7:30:02 PM, 9/24/2022 1:00:02 PM, etc. all DateTime objects). But str_current_date_added_composite is giving me the already-calculated values of the formula (20221001, 20220929, 20220924). I need the formulas instead (=TEXT(I13, "YYYYMMDD"), =TEXT(I14, "YYYYMMDD"), =TEXT(I15, "YYYYMMDD"). Here is how I'm initially retrieving the values:

```
// Grab all data in columns A-J of Items sheet.
var my_range = "Items!A:J";

// Get Values of my_range.
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
  _sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(_spreadsheetId, my_range);

ValueRange response = request.Execute();

// Store response in an IList of an IList of objects.
IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;

// "row" in the snippet above is values[i] in the for loop.
```

I need the formulas because if I am to add anymore records to this sheet, I want to substitute the A1-cell reference in the string to post the new formula to the new cells.

---

**UPDATE:** Adding the following line of code before executing the request:

```
request.ValueRenderOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest.ValueRenderOptionEnum.FORMULA;
```

...did NOT fix the issue. Instead, it displayed the formula in the cell as text, so the value was for example `'=TEXT(I13, "YYYYMMDD")` (with the apostrophe).

Comment: [google-sheets-api-read-cell-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390049/google-sheets-api-read-cell-formula)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're retrieving the formula with the code above and you are adding that formula to the sheet again? If that is the case, can you share the code you're using to add the formula to the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment above is correct: I was totally looking in the wrong area. I originally posted about the retrieval of the original dataset as opposed to the request to post the new data, which is in a different spot.

Here is the relevant code as to why it was posting the value incorrectly:

```
// WRONG: Cell value is stored as string: '=text(I2,"YYYYMMDD") (with apostrophe)
// cd_date_added_composite.UserEnteredValue.StringValue =
//   gsr_current_row.Cells[9].CellValue;

// CORRECT: The formula is posted and the formula's result is displayed in the cell.
cd_date_added_composite.UserEnteredValue.FormulaValue =
  gsr_current_row.Cells[9].CellValue;
```